# Manipulating Single quote in string

Tags: shell, sh

I am running below shell script

```
     var1="'"
    json_variable=$var1{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}$var1
    echo $json_variable
```

I am getting below output

```
'{id:158,name:stackoverflow}'
```

How can I get output in below format

```
'{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}'
```

Thanks,

Comment: Uhh... What's wrong with `json_variable='{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}'`?

Comment: Excuse the reminder, Ganesh, are you forgetting to accept answers? Seems you did until July but haven’t done recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
json_variable="'{\"id\":158,\"name\":\"stackoverflow\"}'"
```

or perhaps you want

```
json_variable="'"'{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}'"'"
```

or

```
json_variable=\''{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}'\'
```

or

```
read json_variable << \EOF
> '{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}'
> EOF
```

Comment: I like this one `json_variable=\''{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}'\'` (your 3rd)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need single quotes specifically in the output, but your root problem is that your assignment never adds the double quotes in the first place. First, quote the double quotes properly, using

```
json_variable='{"id":158,"name":"stackoverflow"}'
```

Then, add the single quotes to the `echo` command:

```
echo "'$json_variable'"
```

The same trick can be used to add single quotes to the value without worrying about complicated quoting schemes.

```
json_variable="'$json_variable'"
```